# The serie of constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

I have written this Node class:

```
template<class T>
struct Node{
    Node() : content(), col(RED), parent(0), left(0), right(0) {}
    Node(const Node& orig) : content(orig.content), col(orig.col), parent(orig.parent), left(orig.left), right(orig.right) {}
    virtual ~Node() {}
    Node<T>& operator= (const Node<T>& node);
    template <class sT>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Node<sT>&node);
    T content;
    Color col;
    Node<T> *parent,*left,*right;
};
```

Now i would create a Node object with within a Node with within a std::pair and I have written this:

```
Node<Node< pair<int,char> > > n1 (Node<pair<int,char> >( pair<int,char>(45,'a') ));
```

but the compiler shows me this error:

```
main.cpp:31:84: error: no matching function for call to ‘Node<std::pair<int, char> >::Node(std::pair<int, char>)’
```

Which is the exact syntax to get what I want?

Comment: You'll have to provide a constructor signature like `Node(const T& x);` to be able to do so.

Comment: That's the compiler giving you the error, not the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a constructor: `Node(const T& x);`

Comment: That would solve the syntactical errors, but I have no idea for a meaningful implementation for this, as seen from the OP's context. (That's why unconcsious upvoting for answers that should be comments is bad!)